# How to run PowerShell Start-Process without closing the output window?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, msbuild

I am trying to run the following PowerShell command in CMD:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process MSBuild.exe MyProject.sln -Verb RunAs"
```

I'm running this in PowerShell so that I can get the UAC (for elevated privileges). I'm not sure if there is an equivalent in CMD.

Now, I run the PowerShell script from within a batch file, so that I can double-click and execute. (or put it in the `$Path` location and call it from anywhere)

But the problem is as soon as it finishes running, it immediately closes, and I cannot see the build error message if any.

How can I `wait` or `pause` when `MSBuild.exe` has finished executing in a new window?

Comment: run that from powershell_ise and you do not need to invoke it as a process.rather you can directly invoke using &. :)

Comment: [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) has a switch `-NoNewWindow` that should run the command in the current window, can you try that?

Comment: PS: you can parse the output to take any further action in your script: ```$Buildresult= & $msbuild $solutionFile 
$NoErrorFound=$buildresult -match "0 Error\(s\)"```

Comment: `Start-Process` has also ```-Wait``` parameter?

Comment: @Curios tried -wait does not work.

Comment: @ZammyPage `-Command "Start-Process MSBuild.exe MyProject.sln  -Verb RunAs ; Read-Host"` ?

Comment: @DanielMorritt tried -NoNewWindow does not work.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Read_Host does not help. The window closes immediately.

Comment: @ZammyPage try `-NoNewWindow` and `Read-Host`?  if `Read-Host` is in there at the very least the window should not be closing.

Comment: `Pause` is a built-in PS function.  It holds the PS window until you press Enter.  I'm not sure you can save your `.exe` output since that's on you.  If your `.exe` has console output, you can redirect it to a variable with `Start-Process`

Answer (score 1):

The `noexit` command keeps your PowerShell window open.

`powershell -noexit -Command "Start-Process MSBuild.exe MyProject.sln -Verb RunAs"`

Answer (score 0):

in your batch file, add `pause` to the end

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process MSBuild.exe MyProject.sln -Verb RunAs"
pause
```

The issue you're seeing is the command window closing after executing everything in the batch file, rather than powershell closing the shell after it executes.